# Power BI M or DAX - Combine results of subquery (or measure) in aggregate with each row of a table, then roll up by date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am looking for a way to roll up aggregates over time of a subquery and a time series in either DAX or M. The solutions I can think of are a measure applied per row in an aggregate in DAX, or join on a subquery expression in M, but I cannot find the functions to do this in the documentation.

An example SQL Solution:

```
SELECT
    t1.Date,
    t1.Month,
    DailyOccupancy - Capacity 'Availability',
    r.Rate,
    (DailyOccupancy - Capacity) * r.Rate 'OverUnderCost'
FROM
    Rate r 
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    d.Date,
    d.Month,
    SUM(c.Capacity) 'DailyCapacity',
    SUM(o.Occupancy) 'DailyOccupancy'
FROM
    DimDate d
    INNER JOIN Capacity c ON d.Date > c.StartDate AND d.Date < c.EndDate
    INNER JOIN Occupancy o ON d.Date = o.Date
GROUP BY
    d.Date,
    d.Month,
    r.Rate
) t1 ON o.Date = t1.Date
```

DAX Measures (works at the individual time step, but when using Capacity measure and a month worth of Occupancy, I get a single Capacity value and 30 Occupancy values summed)

```
DailyCapacity =
VAR currentDate = MAX ( DimDate[Date] )
RETURN
CALCULATE ( SUM('Capacity'[Capacity]),
FILTER ( 'Capacity',
( 'Capacity'[StartDate] <= currentDate
&& 'Capacity'[EndDate] >= currentDate )))

Available =  CALCULATE(SUM('Occupancy'[Occupancy]) - ('Capacity'[DailyCapacity ]))
(Works for each individual time step, doesn't roll up over time)
```

Is there a DAX method to sum the Capacity measure minus the Available aggregate **for each timestep**?

Another approach is to use M to create a "DailyCapacity" table. In SQL:

```
SELECT 
    d.Date,
    SUM(c.Capacity) 'DailyCapacity',
FROM
    DimDate d
    INNER JOIN Capacity c ON d.Date > c.StartDate AND d.Date < c.EndDate
GROUP BY
    d.Date
```

but I can't find a way to join on a boolean expression in M, only keys. Is there a way to join on a **boolean expression**, not **keys** in M?

My tables:

```
DimDate (Date, day, Month, Year, Billing Month, FY)
----------
1/1/2019, 1, 1, 2019, 1, 2019
1/2/2019, 2, 1, 2019, 1, 2019
... Every time step possible


Capacity (StartDate, EndDate, Capacity, Notes)
----------
1/1/2019, 12/31/2019, 40, "Annual Cap"
6/1/2019, 9/15/2019, 30, "Summer Peak"

Occupancy (Date, Occupancy, Location)
----------
1/1/2019, 20, 1
1/1/2019, 17, 2
1/2/2019, 30, 1
1/2/2019, 9, 2
1/3/2019, 22, 1
1/3/2019, 20, 2

Rate (Date, Rate)
----------
1/1/2019, $49.99
1/2/2019, $64.99
... etc.
```

Needed Output

```
Available Space:
----------
1/1/2019, 3
1/2/2019, 1
1/3/2019, -2
1/4/2019, 0
```

And aggregates on rolled up time steps:

SUM(Available Space * Current Day's Rate) per month, quarter, year, etc. Including over and under capacity totals as negative and positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in DAX, let's write a `DailyCapacity` measure (very similar to yours) that we'll use in another measure. (I use `SELECTEDVALUE` here so it's more obvious if I'm dealing with more than one value but your `MAX` and `SUM` should work too.)

```
DailyCapacity =
VAR currentDate = SELECTEDVALUE ( DimDate[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Capacity[Capacity] ),
        FILTER (
            Capacity,
            Capacity[StartDate] <= currentDate &&
            Capacity[EndDate] >= currentDate
        )
    )
```

Now to calculated available space, we'll iterate through each row of `Occupancy` and call the measure we just defined (assuming your `DimDate` table has a relationship that filters `Occupancy`).

```
AvailableSpace = SUMX ( Occupancy, [DailyCapacity] - Occupancy[Occupancy] )
```

This measure should roll up as expected since it's computing the daily capacity for each row, not just once.

Similarly, if you write a measure for `DailyRate` like you did for `DailyCapacity`, then you can write an opportunity cost measure `SUMX ( DimDate, [AvailableSpace] * [DailyRate] )`.

Comment: Okay, one more wrinkle. Occupancy is actually a SUM of several rows in the Occupancy table. 4 locations, each with some occupancy, which is shared, so when I SUMX(Occupancy, DailyCapacity - Occupancy) I evaluate 4 rows, applying DailyCapacity x 4. Updating question now...

Comment: Then write a measure for occupancy and do `AvailableSpace = SUMX ( DimDate, [DailyCapacity] - [OccupancyMeasure] )` instead.